# Custom TimeShift function gives warning output all the time

Tags: java, date, groovy, jmeter

My custom timeShift function in jMeter 5.4.1 outputs "Text cannot be parsed to a Duration" all the time. I'm using groovy 3.0.7 built-in language. Function looks like this:

```
$(__timeShift(yyyyMMdd,,P$(RandomGeneratedVariable)D,, outputDate)
```

This "**RandomGeneratedVariable**" is generated by simple Random Variable generator controller built-in jMeter. My goal was to create a current date + randomly generated number 000-999 everytime when some script is using '**outputDate**' variable. Funny though it works. I'm getting randomly generated date that passes system validation. Is it just a jMeter known issue or my function is wrongly created?

Best Regards!

Comment: I bet it's your function. But you didn't provide the code. So, just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it using your approach:

[image]

So the only option I can think of is that your `${RandomGeneratedVariable}` variable doesn't have its anticipated value, double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination

In case you won't be able to get to the root cause of the error you can replace the variable with JMeter's [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like

```
${__timeShift(yyyyMMdd,,P${__Random(0,999)}D,,outputDate)}
```

[image]

---

You mention `groovy 3.0.7 built-in language` however I also fail to see where and how it can be used, JMeter Functions are being evaluated in the place where they're being called, there is no need to perform any extra coding on top of them, if you do - you're supposed to share your code in order to get support